# converting datetime value to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, int

I am trying to make the passed_days variable an integer, so that I can add the values. So if `passed_days = 1`, `passed_days` should equal an integer not a datetime.

I tried converting the `passed_days` var to as a int like `int(passed_days)`.
This is the current code I have now:

```
start_day = datetime.date(2019, 7, 11)
current_day = datetime.date.today()
passed_days = current_day - start_day
current = 183

if passed_days > datetime.timedelta(days=0):
    current = 183 + passed_days
else:
    current = 183
```

I need the output to be something like...184 + 2

Answer (score -1):

To get the days represented by a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), use the `days` property like:

```
passed_days.days
```

#### Testcode:

```
import datetime as dt

start_day = dt.date(2019, 7, 11)
current_day = dt.date.today()
passed_days = current_day - start_day

print(type(passed_days.days))
print(passed_days.days)
```

#### Results:

```
<class 'int'>
0
```